# Que biblioteca do Java que retorna o idioma do computador?

Tags: java

```
package horadosistema;

import java.util.Date;

public class HoraDoSistema {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Date relogio = new Date();

     System.out.println("A hora do sistema é");
     System.out.println(relogio.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: A pergunta diz "idioma do sistema", mas o código pega a data, sua pergunta não faz muito sentido. Edite-a e explique melhor sua duvida.

Comment: "system de sistema"

Comment: O que esse código tem a ver com o título da pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar a classe `java.lang.System`:

```
System.getProperty("user.country");
```

Ou tente usar a `java.util.Locale`:

```
Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
currentLocale.getDisplayLanguage();
```

Para recuperar a data/hora do sistema, utilizando o `java.util.Date`:

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String todayStr = df.format(today);
```